# How to copy the values of an array in java into a new array excluding min and max values?

Tags: java

I have a home work problem like this:

The following data represent Richter Scale data for earthquakes. Write a program to calculate and print the average of any valid earthquake data.

Store the Richter values in an array of doubles named quakeLevels.

Unfortunately, your seismograph is known to sometimes produce unreliable readings (like the value of 10.1 in this example). So you decide to throw out the maximum and minimum readings.

Your program should do the following:

- Declare and initialize the quakeLevels array using the following data. 
  { 5.6, 6.2, 4.0, 5.5, 5.7, 6.1,7.4, 8.5, 5.5, 6.3, 6.4, 2.1, 6.9, 4.3, 3.1, 7.0, 10.1 }
- Determine the maximum and minimum values in the array.
- Compute the average of the array contents, excluding the maximum and minimum values.
- Print the values in the array excluding the maximum and minimum values.
- Print the average.

Complete your code below:

I have tried this problem with the following code but I am getting null values for the new array.

```
public class QuakeLevels {


    public static void main(String[] args) {



        Double quakeLevels[] = { 5.6, 6.2, 4.0, 5.5, 5.7, 6.1,7.4, 8.5, 5.5, 6.3, 6.4, 2.1, 6.9, 4.3, 3.1, 7.0, 10.1 };
        Double minQuakeLevel = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        Double maxQuakeLevel = Double.MIN_VALUE;
        double totalQuakeLevels =0.0;
        double avgQuakeLevels =0.0;
        Double[] newQuakeLevels = new Double[(quakeLevels.length-2)]; //array excluding min and max value from the original
        for(int i=0;i<quakeLevels.length;i++){
              totalQuakeLevels+=quakeLevels[i];
          if(quakeLevels[i]<minQuakeLevel) {
                minQuakeLevel=quakeLevels[i];
          }
          if(quakeLevels[i]>maxQuakeLevel){
                maxQuakeLevel =quakeLevels[i];
            }


        }



         avgQuakeLevels = ((double)totalQuakeLevels-(minQuakeLevel+maxQuakeLevel))/(quakeLevels.length-2); // Excluding min and max Quake Levels to calculate average
         System.out.printf("%s%.1f\n","Average Quake Level= ",avgQuakeLevels); 
         System.out.print("The new quake level:");
         for(int i=0;i<quakeLevels.length-2;i++){

          if(newQuakeLevels[i]!=minQuakeLevel && newQuakeLevels[i]!=maxQuakeLevel){
              quakeLevels[i]=newQuakeLevels[i];


         System.out.printf("%6s",newQuakeLevels[i]);
           }

         }
          System.out.println("");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're setting the wrong array. You're overwritting the original array, but you don't write the new array.

Try this:

Instead of

```
if(newQuakeLevels[i]!=minQuakeLevel && newQuakeLevels[i]!=maxQuakeLevel){
      quakeLevels[i]=newQuakeLevels[i];
```

put this

```
if(quakeLevels[i]!=minQuakeLevel && quakeLevels[i]!=maxQuakeLevel){
      newQuakeLevels[i]=quakeLevels[i];
```